# SQL: Why is my query not returning values with a zero quantity?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For some reason, my query is only returning 26 rows instead of 69 rows. It is omitting all the rows where the quantity is zero. I think there is a problem with the `WHERE` clause. I wrote that obscene line because I didn't know how else to make the query return values based on 1 of these 2 scenarios:

1. User supplies a quantity -> return only rows with that quantity
2. User does not supply a quantity -> return all quantities

How can I make it so that the query returns all rows if the user does not supply a value and also maybe clean up my non-optimal `WHERE` clause?

```
    DECLARE @lp varchar(30) = '1250116'
    DECLARE @qty decimal

    SELECT

        t.lp_num,
        t.qty

    FROM

        ISW_LPTrans AS t

    WHERE

        ((t.qty >-5000000000 AND t.qty < 5000000000))
```

**2nd attempt:** this didn't work either though, it still only returns 26 rows.
**Edit:** Sorry! Copied the query from above but forgot to change the line that I fiddled with!

```
    DECLARE @lp varchar(30) = '1250116'
    DECLARE @qty decimal = NULL;

    SELECT

        t.lp_num,
        t.qty

    FROM

        ISW_LPTrans AS t

    WHERE

        (@qty IS NULL OR t.qty = @qty)
```

Comment: which of the 2 `where` clauses is being used?

Comment: @vkp I tried both, neither worked correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - Conditional WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329674/sql-conditional-where-clause)

Comment: now your first and second attempts are the same.....  I am not sure what you want in your where clause but just build a case statement an example is below in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure what you want for the where clause because your edits have changed the meaning a couple of times, but you can just build a case statement in your where clause and test for your conditions.

```
DECLARE @lp varchar(30) = '1250116'
DECLARE @qty decimal

SELECT

    t.lp_num,
    t.qty

FROM

    ISW_LPTrans AS t

WHERE
   (CASE
      WHEN @qty IS NULL THEN 1
      WHEN t.qty = @qty THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END) = 1
```

Comment: I got an error: `Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`

Comment: I just want to let the user either specify a quantity or leave it blank. If they leave it blank, it should return all rows regardless of quantity.

Comment: that is what this query should do for you not sure why you got the system.outofmemory though as unless your system is very under resourced for the size of this table it shouldn't be a burden.

Comment: My mistake, it was because I forgot to put in the conditions for `t.lp_num`. This worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to need to do is use a T-SQL IF ELSE Clause.

Here is the official T-SQL Spec
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

In your case you will need to perform the following:

```
DECLARE @qty decimal = 11.00 or
DECLARE @qty decimal = null

IF @qty IS NULL
    SELECT

        t.lp_num,
        t.qty

    FROM

        ISW_LPTrans AS t

ELSE

   SELECT

        t.lp_num,
        t.qty

    FROM

        ISW_LPTrans AS t

WHERE t.qty = @qty
```

Comment: Is there a way to compact this so that I don't have to basically write 2 queries? I ask because the real project SELECTs many more fields, each with its own parameter.

Comment: Jack while this would return the desired results conditional where clauses that support both in a single query would be the more standard answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this query:

```
SELECT t.lp_num, t.qty from  ISW_LPTrans AS t
    where  ISNULL(t.qty,'') = '' or t.qty = @qty
```

Comment: Please also try to explain what the query does and how it solves the problem. Also, if you already tried it paste the output.